# Spring Boot concurrent access to Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

Starting to integrate Redis in a Spring Boot application that needs concurrent access to it (Redis), I need advice on the best practice in order to continue the implementation.

Redis connection is setup like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        try {
            return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log...
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        try {
            redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
            redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
            redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log ...
        }
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

There are entities saved in Redis using a repository like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RedisHash
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item {
    @Id
    private String id;

    // ...
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String> {
}
```

A service to manage the items:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemsService {
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

...
    private manageItem(Item item) {
        // ...
        // set item data
        // NEEDS LOCKING
        itemRepository.save(item);
        // ...
    }
...
}
```

At this point, must implement the concurrent access to this Redis data. Reading multiple articles about this, I wonder what is the right implementation to follow in order to be able to delete an `item` from Redis when this is not accessed by another save call from the `ItemRepository`, in a scheduled task. It's a cleanup when the `item` was not used for a specific time and meets some conditions. So the task should come, make a list of them and delete them if they are not accessed at the time (even unlikely), by trying to acquire a lock and delete. If the lock is not successful, should let them alone for the next run.

So the question is: in the `@Repository` context, should implement a `RedisLockRegistry` or a custom lock by using some Redis commands? How would this look like? What is the right beans design?

Comment: hey bro, did you find the answer to this question? And do you still have this question? Because I think it is solvable.

Comment: Well, I have an implementation with a lock managed in redis, but that introduces delays. Technically works, similat ro this one here: https://github.com/crossoverJie/distributed-redis-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/com/crossoverjie/distributed/lock/RedisLock.java.